# How to obtain firebase libraries, e.g. firebase-messaging-9.4.0.jar

Tags: android, maven, gradle, firebase, jcenter

I am trying to do an automated android build in a local network segment (ie. without access to public jcenter or maven repositories). In order to do that I need to provide all dependencies in a local maven repository which is referenced from the root build.gradle. (NB: if I use the android-maven-plugin instead of gradle the situation is the same).

This works fine, only I have difficulties locating the firebase libraries like firebase-core-9.4.0.jar or firebase-messaging-9.4.0.jar. According to the gradle console output they are searched in a location

```
<server>/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/9.4.0/firebase-messaging-9.4.0.jar
```

This location does not exist in the public jcenter or maven repositories.

Does anyone know where to find them?

---

edit: I have observed Android Studio on empty caches using Wireshark (using http for the jcenter repository). The results are rather mysterious. It issues a GET request for

http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/9.4.0/firebase-messaging-9.4.0.jar

This request is redirected to

http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-release-bintray/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/9.4.0/firebase-messaging-9.4.0.jar?referrer

The latter GET request results in HTTP 404 as the repo.jfrog.org repository has no content in the firebase-messaging/ directory. However, Android Studio extracts the jar files in the build directory and continues to build the project.It is unclear, where the jar files come from.

Comment: Do you have the given jar file? Could you post your build.gradle file?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want to do. Add the jar to a local maven repository? Add the reference to the jar in you build file?

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: Yes, thank you, I have elaborated my use case in a comment to your answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can show all librarys in the oficial support.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: You can also download librarys here:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.firebase

Comment: Thanks, but his is not the right place. The build.gradle dependency refers to something with groupId "com.google.firebase" and artifactId "firebase-messaging". This is not available on mvnrepository.com.

Answer (score 1):

Found this link, hope this help

https://github.com/unity-plugins/Google-Firebase-SDK

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup), you should add to you build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
```

and that to your app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  // ...
}

dependencies {
  // ...
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
  // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
  // the latest Google Repository in the Android SDK manager
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I am aware of this, and for building the APK out of Android Studio my gradle files look exactly like this, and it works.

Comment: However, what I'm trying to do is an automated build in a sandbox environment. For that I change the root build.gradle so that it no longer references jcenter.bintray.com but an internal repositoryinstead. In order for that to work, all external dependencies including the firebase libraries need to be copied to said internal repository. I can find most external dependencies, but not the firebase libraries. Hence my question.

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2020**

Firebase `aar` are now available on maven repository at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase

For example, firebase-core `aar` is at https://maven.google.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/17.4.4/firebase-core-17.4.4.aar